# How to quickly map multiple numpy array with a function to single array of different object

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, lambda

Say I have 4 numpy arrays like:

```
a : np.random.randn(4,4)
```

which is like

```
array([[ 0.8087178 , -1.32970726, -0.62254544,  0.82266235],
   [-0.57101685, -1.39512136, -0.19650182,  0.46574661],
   [-1.06096896,  0.92744505,  1.98807088,  1.11976449],
   [-0.0103123 ,  1.49460442, -0.16151632,  0.96951708]])
```

then I have `b, c, d` also equal `np.random.randn(4,4)`

Now, suppose I want to know the maximum of for each array location in string, like this:

```
 array([[a, b, d, c],
        [b, c, a, a],
        [c, a, b, b],
        [d, c, a, b]])
```

How would I do it? lambda function don't seem to work here. I know a loop would work, but is there a batch function that could do this?

More generally, the question would be, how could I apply individual functions to each array element across arrays without using a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: What is 'lambda function'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
np.argmax((a,b,c,d),axis=0)
```

This will give you an array where `0` means `a`, `1` means `b`, and so on.
If you really care, you can then just apply the map `dict(zip(range(4),'abcd'))` to it.

For the "more general" question, you are looking at `numpy.vectorize`.

Comment: `np.array(['a','b','c','d'])[np.argmax((a,b,c,d),axis=0)]` will return the matrix OP was looking for. +1

Answer (score 0):

For your main question: if you stack the arrays together using `np.concatenate` then you can use `np.argmax` to get an array that shows which array has the greatest element in each position. The example below shows this for 1D arrays. You'll want `axis=2` for 2D arrays.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [3]: a2 = np.array([3, 2, 1, 1])

In [4]: a1
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [5]: a2
Out[5]: array([3, 2, 1, 1])

In [6]: np.concatenate([a1, a2])
Out[6]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1])

In [7]: np.concatenate([[a1], [a2]])
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 2, 1, 1]])

In [9]: ai = np.concatenate([[a1], [a2]])

In [11]: np.argmax(ai, axis=1)
Out[11]: array([3, 0])

In [12]: np.argmax(ai, axis=0)
Out[12]: array([1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Your other question "how could I apply individual functions to each array element across arrays without using a loop?" is unclear. I don't understand what it means but it should probably be a separate question.